# How to pass ATPL as an ATC?

Tags: air-traffic-control, easa-regulations, easa, atpl

i have graduated from Nation Aviation Academy and my occupation is Air Traffic Control. But to become a pilot was my childhood dream. So my question is, is it possible to pass atpl exams in this situation or is it necessary to pass the pilot course? I already have medicine and icao level. Thanks in advance for answering my question.

Comment: You can't just skip PPL and CPL to become ATPL. What do you mean when you say that you have "medicine and ICAO level"?

Comment: I have medical certificate class 1 and English level 4 i meant that. So can i pass PPL and CPL as an ATC?

Comment: You can take the PPL and CPL courses without an ATC. The "ATC" part has no bearing on your quest to get an ATPL, it doesn't allow you to bypass anything.

Comment: I meant that i am ATC, is it enough to pass PPL or CPL without any course? is my background enough for just passing exams but not taking course?

Comment: I doubt it. You'd probably ace the airspace and weather stuff, but there is a lot of other things in there. Plus you need an instructors endorsement or certificate of graduation from a course to take the tests. BTW, just passing the course doesn't mean you get a PPL or CPL, you still need experience requirements and check rides.

Comment: thank you for helping

Comment: If your only goal is to take the written test for personal fulfillment I can't imagine a commercial test facility would refuse to take your money.  As others have pointed out, this won't get you an ATPL, just a passing written test score.  (if you can pass...)  I might be wrong, but I don't think an instructor endorsement is a hard requirement just to have a go at the written.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Are you asking about a specific country? Regulations and licensing can be very different in different places. Being a controller would certainly help with some things, but ultimately you still have to learn how to fly an aircraft.

Comment: @MichaelHall Most test facilities will not allow you to take a test without an instructor endorsement. You can find practice tests online if it's just "personal gratification", but anything that is official requires official process.

Comment: Thanks Ron.  Just sayin' though, if it ain't prohibited by CFR, cash talks!  ;)

Comment: A Google search for "Nation Aviation Academy" does not find anything. Please tell us which country are asking about.

Comment: @MichaelHall - Part 61.35 does require an instructor endorsements. CATS/PSI locations in my area will not let you sit for the PPL, IR, or CPL without endorsements. You can get around that by taking one of the many online courses available. They will send you a pdf endorsements to take to the testing center. Here’s the catch. You can take the BGI, AGI, CFI, and CFII without endorsements. And, the question banks are nearly 90% identical to the tests that require endorsements.

Comment: Thanks for the reference Dean!

Answer (score 3):

Being an Air Traffic Controller does not provide any legal shortcuts for piloting courses, in any jurisdiction as far as I am aware. Sure, you could probably sleep through the lectures on meteorology and maybe parts of others, but you still need to sit and pass all 14 exams. You would have little to no advantage on the subjects of aerodynamics, aircraft systems, performance and loading, and human factors.

You also need to complete the practical flight training and meet the same requirements as everyone else.